# In Js Css and HTML how can I make an image element's image not fill up the whole element?

Tags: javascript, css, image

So, I'm trying make some JS code that can create diffenet types of HTML elements. They can have a height of 50px or 100px. Ive been using this code to do so.

```
function spawnNote(position, duration, noteNum){
  const element = document.createElement("img");
  //sets up basic stuff that all notes share
  element.style.width = "50px";
  element.style.top = "50px";
  element.style.position = "fixed";
  element.classList.add("newElement");
  element.id = "note" + noteNum;
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  document.getElementById(`note` + noteNum).src = "temp.jpeg"

  //now, this sets the specifics for each note
  if(position == "left"){
    element.style.left = "10px"
  } else {
    element.style.left = "100px"
  }

  if(duration == 1){
    element.style.height = "50px";
  } else {
    element.style.height = "100px";
  }
}
```

I want to add the same image to both types, but have it so that the smaller note only has the top half of the same image. I don't want to use the same image to do both things, but I can't figure out how to not make the background image not squish or stretch.

Sorry if this is super confusing

I've tried using (in the CSS)

```
.newElement {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

It works for the bigger element, but it shoves the image into the middle for the smaller one.

Ive tried a lot of other stuff, but nothings worked so far.

Comment: can you please add some code snippet over here, I will help me to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by "shoves the image into the middle for the smaller one"?

Comment: What it does it centers the file image into the center of the image element; it cuts off the top and bottom

Answer (score -1):

As described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position):

> The object-position CSS property specifies the alignment of the selected replaced element's contents within the element's box.

This will allow the image to appear cropped as you requested, only showing the top portion.

The css would therefore look like this:

```css
.newElement {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you I'm terrible with css

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).